# how to make a long url spread into two lines

Tags: css, url, drupal-6, hyperlink, line-breaks

I have a very narrow column and a three-word URL that is pushing wider that the column's original width.

can i force the three words to spread over two or three lines and keep the URL link intact?

I am using css to style a custom drupal theme and the length/name of this url is a Drupal node name turned into a tab via the QuickTabs module, so I need to manage it via css, preferrably. I have the feeling this is a very easy fix, but I have searched thru Google and I cannot find anything that works for me.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what i usually do with really long urls is to truncate it (using ruby or whatever floats your boat) to something like http://sdfksdf.... then add the whole url as a title so the user can mouseover it and see where it leads to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

I don't think its supported in all browsers though.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jrRqb/ for an example

Comment: Thanx. One more question: should I use it in the <ul>, the <li> or the <a>? I guess I also have to specify my 33% width in the <li> tag, right?

Comment: @MauF, depends on how you style you list. Post an example on jsFiddle and I can have a look. (I think it should be on a block element)

Comment: Actually, Peath, the dev site is here: http://dev2.s-peak.com/ It's fairliy easy to know which tabs are the ones I'm talking about.

Comment: @MauF, sorry I can't see it on that site. It is however very broken in my browser (Firefox 5)

Comment: I meant to correct my previous post before I sent it. Sorry, Petah.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the purest answer, but sometimes a `<br />` in the link text is the easiest thing.

```
<p><a href="http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/benedict_xvi/travels/2011/index_croazia_en.htm">http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/benedict_xvi/<br />travels/2011/index_croazia_en.htm</a></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8xmU5/

Comment: Unless the link is dynamically generated.